# How to display Login wise data in whole application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I make database for signup and login, i authenticate when user is enter email and password in signup form then and then he/she login.

Now i want to display userwise data in application means eg. user A and user B, if user A login and enter the data in database then only user A is show his/her entered data not user B. Same way user B is enter data in database then and then only user B show his/her entered data.

I have signup,login,account,expense,income tables. In short i want to display user wise data in whole application.

Comment: Create a user table in database and set all user information. Then set primary key for differentiating each user. and then get information according to the user.

Comment: i create primary key in sid field in signup table, after i create foreign key in login table. but i m not success for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display Login wise data in whole application using sqlite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126130/how-to-display-login-wise-data-in-whole-application-using-sqlite-database)